# How to change the black background color of a web page when opening a picture in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

For example, open this URL in Chrome: https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/se-logo.png

The page background is black. How to change this to a brighter color?

I tried to write a userscript to change the style of the body element, but it will flash from black to the color I want, it's still annoying.

Is there a better way to reach this?

Comment: `page background is black` ... that is not page background ... it is not part of the webpage

Comment: @jsotola yeah you are right, it's not a part of the webpage, but the default style by Chrome, solved with the Stylus extension.